# Top-level StreamBlock within StreamField doesn't render in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm attempting to use a StreamBlock like the last snippet in the section of the docs [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8/topics/streamfield.html#streamblock), as the only argument to a StreamField. It's working perfectly in the Wagtail admin, but when trying to render in the template nothing appears. I tried using the default template and just include_block, but nothing is rendered. I also tried using a custom template and include_block, and the custom template is hit, but I haven't been able to render anything useful from there. I reverted to trying to use the default template in the following code.

home/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import StreamFieldPanel

from home.blocks import HeroImageStreamBlock


class HomePage(Page):
    hero_image = StreamField(HeroImageStreamBlock(
            block_counts={
                'hero_button': {'max_num': 1},
                'is_active': {'max_num': 1},
                'is_randomized': {'max_num': 1},
            }
        )
        , blank=True
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('hero_image'),
    ]
```

home/blocks.py:

```
from wagtail.core import blocks
from wagtail.images.blocks import ImageChooserBlock


class HeroButtonBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    button_text = blocks.CharBlock(required=False)
    button_page = blocks.PageChooserBlock(required=False)
    button_url = blocks.URLBlock(required=False)
    is_active = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False,
                                    help_text="""When checked, this hero button is active. 
                             NOTE: Only the first active hero button will be displayed.""")

    class Meta:
        icon = "link"


class HeroTextBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    hero_text = blocks.CharBlock(required=False)
    is_active = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False,
                                    help_text="""When checked, this hero text is active. 
                                 NOTE: Only the first active hero text will be displayed.""")

    class Meta:
        icon = "edit"


class HeroImageBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    """This is the StructBlock for the hero images."""
    background_image = ImageChooserBlock()
    is_active = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False,
                                    help_text="""When checked, this hero image is active.""")

    class Meta:
        icon = "image"


class HeroImagesListBlock(blocks.ListBlock):
    class Meta:
        icon = "media"


class HeroImageStreamBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    """This is the container StreamBlock for the hero image."""
    hero_images = HeroImagesListBlock(HeroImageBlock())
    text = HeroTextBlock()
    hero_button = HeroButtonBlock()
    is_randomized = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False,
                                        label="Is Randomized?",
                                        help_text="When checked, images will load in random order.")
    is_active = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False,
                                    help_text="""When checked, this hero image is active. 
                             NOTE: Only the first active hero image will be displayed.""")
```

home/templates/home/home_page.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
    test
    {% include_block page.hero_image %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm pretty new to python/django/wagtail, so hoping it's just a simple/conceptual error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this wasn't working because the blocks created in the admin were still in draft state, not published (facepalm). Once published, this works perfectly.